# Expecting an error with axios-mock-adapter

Tags: javascript, jestjs, axios, axios-mock-adapter

I am trying to test an axios get request with `axios-mock-adapter`, such that an error is thrown given a status that does not equal 200. However, when I execute the test (see `api.test.js`), I get the following message:

> Error: expect(function).toThrowError(undefined)
>
> Expected the function to throw an error. But it didn't throw anything.

How do I test to make sure that an error is thrown, using `axios-mock-adapter` using my `get` and `handleResponse` methods? Thanks!

**api.test.js:**

```
import axios from 'axios';
import MockAdapter from 'axios-mock-adapter';

const handleResponse = (response) => {
  if (response.status !== 200) {
    throw new Error('foo');
  } else {
    return response.data;
  }
};

const get = async (url) => {
  const response = await axios.get(url, {withCredentials: true});
  return handleResponse(response);
};

test('testing that, when making a get request to the appropriate url, an error is thrown ' +
     ' when status !== 200', async () => {
  new MockAdapter(axios)
    .onGet('sampleUrl')
    .reply(500, {data: 'payload'});
  const expectedError = async () => {
    await get('sampleUrl');
  };
  expect(expectedError).toThrowError();
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem I'm seeing in your code is that `expect().toThrowError()` expects an synchronous exception, but your code is actually rejecting a promise. The bit that may be confusing is that you see `throw new Error('foo');` in your `handleResponse`. That's throwing an exception, true. However, *because this code is called by an `async` function* this exception is converted to a promise rejection. So `await get('sampleUrl')` does not result in a synchronous exception being thrown but in an asynchronous promise rejection.

Looking at Jest's [documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#rejects), it seems to me that you should be doing:

```
return expect(expectedError()).rejects.toThrowError();
```

You need to call `expectedError` because it is a function that returns a promise, and you need to use `.rejects` to converts the rejection to a plain exception that can be tested with `.toThrowError()`. Make sure to return the assertion, or `await` it. Otherwise you'll have dangling promise.

Comment: You rock man, was wrapping my head around this for a while now, your solution worked like a charm!